# How to install QtCurve 'tar.gz' theme in Kubuntu 12.04?

Tags: kubuntu, themes, kde

I have downloaded this theme from [kde-look](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/?content=150944).

How I can install it? I copied the uncompressed files to `~.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme/` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme/` [This path is for  **Plasma Themes**]

Your theme is a **QT curve style**, go to **System Settings > Application Appearance > Style** then where it says **Widget Style**, select **qtcurve** from the dropdown list, then click apply. You can import your qtcurve theme and configure it by clicking on the "Configure" button next it.

You must install QTcurve first with `sudo apt-get install qtcurve`.

Comment: i did that. I moved uncompresed file to  ~.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme/  and doesnt works

Comment: I see that the Theme you want is a QT curve style, you choose those in the KDE system settings>appearence>colors.

Comment: Yes, but nothing in color styles, only default system schemas

Comment: Check the Edited answer.

Comment: in application appearance > style only have to set graphic styles (oxigen,cleanlooks,etc ) and a demo of the selected style

Comment: Do you have qtcurve installed?

Comment: well, thats the problem, thanks for your help uri

Comment: wrong path here please correct ~.kde/sha to ~/.kde/sha

Answer (score 1):

Click on system ---> preferencence ---> appearance
drag'n'drop into this window and then click on customize and select the theme you have copied before.
from http://ubuntuforums.org